# I am trying to print the elements of linked list after adding it but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to show the items in my linked list after inserting them with the function Add, and view function to print but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
class Linked_List():
    def  __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    def Add(self,value):
        if(self.head == None):
            n = Node(value)
            if(self.head == None):
                self.head = n
            else:
                self.tail.next  = n
            self.tail =  n
def view(head):
        curr = head
        while (curr):
                print(curr.value,"-->")
                curr = curr.next


newlist = Linked_List()
newlist.Add(5)
newlist.Add(6)
newlist.Add(56)
view(newlist.head)
```

It only shows the first element 5 and doesn't show the rest. I can't seem to understand the reason even if I have done acc. to the algorithm?

Comment: What does "i have done acc. to the algo" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If `head` is not `Null`, `Add` doesn't do anything, which even the most rudimentary debugger would have made clear.